# bottom up method development parameter passing

Tags: python

I develop bottom up, starting with small simple methods to go to the big full fledged implementation

```
class Pop(object):

    def welcome(self, name, new_member = False):
        response = ""
        if new_member:
                response = " NOT"
        return str("hello there "+name+", you seem"+response+" to be a member\n")

    def ageVerification(self, name, age, new_member = False):
        the_welcome_string = self.welcome(name, new_member)
        minimum = ""
        excuse = ""
        if age < 16:
            minimum = " NOT"
            excuse = ", sorry"
        return str(the_welcome_string+str(age)+" is"+minimum+" the minimum required age to buy beer in Belgium"+excuse+"\n")

    def theWholething(self, name, age, address, new_member = False):
        if age < 16:
            appology = str("you cannot order any beer\n")
        else:
            appology = str("your beer will be shipped to "+address+"\n")
        return str(self.ageVerification(name, age, new_member)+appology) 
    
# EOF
```

My question is if it is normal that when i reach theWholeThingMethod, I carry along all the parameters of the previously defined methods?  Is this pythonic?

My population class has almost 20 "helper" methods called in theWholeThing, and it seems I am just fiddling with parameters to get them in the right order ...

```
theWholeThing(self,\
              name,\
              age,\
              address,\
              registered = True,\
              first_date_entered,\
              last_date_entered,\
              purchased_amount,\
              favorite_beer,\
              promotional_code,\
              and_so_on0,\
              and_so_on1,\
              and_so_on2,\
              and_so_on3,\
              and_so_on4,\
              and_so_on5,\
              and_so_on6,\
              and_so_on7,\
              and_so_on8,\
              and_so_on9,\
              and_so_on10):
```

Comment: A 20-parameter method or function won't be very readable hence not very pythonic.

Comment: Where do all these parameters *come from*? Could you accumulate or store the parameters themselves in an object (e.g. a class) - and then just pass the one object around? (Or, store the data on `Pop` directly!)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if it is normal that when i reach theWholeThingMethod, I carry along all the parameters of the previously defined methods? Is this pythonic?

Neither.

There is really no point in having a class if all the methods take all the arguments anyway.  These might as well just be functions.

There are many ways this could be done, depending on whether the various parameters are mandatory, or what happens when one is not provided, but here is one possibility:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Pop(object):

    name: str
    age: int
    address: str
    new_member : bool = False

    def welcome(self):
        response = ""
        if self.new_member:
                response = " NOT"
        return str("hello there "+self.name+", you seem"+response+" to be a member\n")

    def ageVerification(self):
        the_welcome_string = self.welcome()
        minimum = ""
        excuse = ""
        if self.age < 16:
            minimum = " NOT"
            excuse = ", sorry"
        return str(the_welcome_string+str(self.age)+" is"+minimum+" the minimum required age to buy beer in Belgium"+excuse+"\n")

    def theWholething(self):
        if self.age < 16:
            appology = str("you cannot order any beer\n")
        else:
            appology = str("your beer will be shipped to "+self.address+"\n")
        return str(self.ageVerification()+appology) 
    
# EOF
```

**Note: @nneonneo had a great suggestion of using a dataclasses, so answer tweaked to incorporate that**

Comment: fwiw: it may be more readable to do this as a data class with defaults in the dataclass definition. Then you won't need to do `setattr` magic.

Comment: Great suggestion @nneonneo, thanks.  Haven't used them much, so didn't cross my mind, but they seem perfect for this.

Comment: would *args and **kwargs not be better solution than dataclass

Comment: @hewi: Probably a matter of personal opinion.  I'd certainly prefer the dataclass over a long list of parameters in the function signature, then all the boiler plate of `self.some_arg = some_arg`